# Intersections of saturated locally free sheaves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, examples-counterexamples, sheaf-theory, vector-bundles

I've been thinking about vector bundles recently and came up against the following problem. I'm hoping someone can help me with the intution here.

**Background**: In this question, we're working over a base scheme (or variety, if you like) $X$. All sheaves I work with are sheaves of $\mathcal O_X$-modules.

Let $\cal E$ and $\cal E'$ be locally free sheaves on $\mathcal O_X$ and suppose that $\cal E'\subseteq\cal E$. Say that $\mathcal E'$ is a *saturated subsheaf* of $\mathcal E$ if the quotient sheaf $\mathcal E/\mathcal E'$ is again a locally free sheaf.

> **Question**: If the locally free sheaves $\mathcal E'$ and $\mathcal E''$ are saturated subsheaves of the locally free sheaf $\mathcal E$, then is their intersection $\mathcal E'\cap\mathcal E''\subseteq\mathcal E$ locally free? Assuming $\mathcal E'\cap\mathcal E''$ is locally free, is it a saturated subsheaf of $\mathcal E$?
>
> (For both questions, give either a proof or counterexample.)

**Thoughts**:
By taking stalks, you can reduce this question to a problem in commutative algebra. Here $X$ would be a local ring and the locally free sheaves would just be free modules. This reduction might help in the proof, but it hasn't given me much intuition.

If $X$ is a point or a curve then any subsheaf of a locally free sheaf is locally free, meaning that if the first assertion fails, it can only fail in dimension $>2$. This obstruction has made it hard for me to think of examples.

It's tempting to come up with examples just by intersecting the total spaces of the sheaves; then we would be in the situation of [this Math Overflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/7926/about-the-intersection-of-two-vector-bundles). Unfortunately, intersection does not commute with formation of the total space of a vector bundle, so I don't know how to use geometric intuition about vector bundles for this problem.

**Terminological Warning**: Mohan pointed out that my usage of the word "saturated" is nonstandard: the usual definition states that a subsheaf is *saturated* if its cokernel is torsion-free, which is weaker than locally free. However, I'm not going to go back through my question and replace all instances of "saturated".

Sasha proposed that we say $\mathcal E'\to\mathcal E$ is a *fiberwise monomorphism* if its cokernel is locally free. This terminology makes sense, and I should have used it instead of "saturated".

Comment: There is already a notion of saturated, where the quotient is only assumed to be torsion-free, not locally free, so may be you should use another word.

Comment: Ah, I see; thank you for the terminological clarification.

Comment: I would say $\mathcal{E}' \to \mathcal{E}$ is a fiberwise monomorphism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under your assumptions the sheaf $\mathcal{E}' \cap \mathcal{E}''$ is necessarily reflexive, bot not necessarily locally free, as the next example shows.

Let $X = \mathbb{P}^3$, $\mathcal{E} = \mathcal{O}^{\oplus 4}$, with 
$$
\mathcal{E}' = \Omega^1(1) := \mathrm{Ker}(\mathcal{O}^{\oplus 4} \stackrel{(x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3)}\longrightarrow \mathcal{O}(1)), 
$$
and 
$$
\mathcal{E}'' = \mathcal{O}^{\oplus 3} := \mathrm{Ker}(\mathcal{O}^{\oplus 4} \stackrel{(1,0,0,0)}\longrightarrow \mathcal{O}(1)).
$$
Then
$$
\mathcal{E}' \cap \mathcal{E}'' \cong 
\mathrm{Ker}(\mathcal{O}^{\oplus 3} \stackrel{(x_1,x_2,x_3)}\longrightarrow \mathcal{O}(1)),
$$
which is a standard example of a reflexive, but not locally free sheaf.